# Order of a group and subsequent subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove that if the order of a group G is greater than 1 and non-prime, then G has a subgroup other than the trivial subgroups {e} and G itself.

I am confused because I am only being able to prove the case for prime order by using Lagrange’s theorem i.e. if I have a group of order p, where p is a prime number, then the order of subgroups must divide p, hence the order can be either 1 or p.

How do I go about proving the case for non prime order let’s say x > 1?

Comment: Start by choosing a non-identity element $g$ and consider the subgroup consisting of the powers of $g$.

Comment: @DerekHolt So I have tried to solve this problem by dividing into two cases. One where G is cyclic and the other when G is not cyclic. I proved the case for cyclic G but I am having a hard time doing the non-cyclic G. Where do I start? Any hint?

Comment: My previous comment answers your question. The subgroup  generated by $g$ is not equal to $G$ or to $\{ e \}$.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to prove the contrapositive of your statement, which is:
If $G$ has no proper nontrivial subgroup, then $|G|=1$ or is a prime.

Assume that $|G|>1$. Then there exists $x\in G$ where $x\neq e$.
Note that $\langle x\rangle$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$.
By assumption, $G=\langle x \rangle$.
Suppose $|G|$ is composite. Write $|G|=ab$ where $a,b>1$.
It can be shown that $\langle x^a\rangle$ is a proper nontrivial subgroup of $G$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

By [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), if there is a prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, then $G$ has an element $g$ of order $p$, i.e., $U=\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$. Therefore we have found a proper non-trivial subgroup. For example, let $|G|=6$, then we can apply this for $p=2$ and $p=3$.

For a simple proof of Cauchy's Theorem see for example here:

[Simple proof of Cauchy's theorem in Group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437161/simple-proof-of-cauchys-theorem-in-group-theory?rq=1)

Comment: But this problem is completely elementary, and you don't need Cauchy's theorem (or even Lagrange's theorem) to solve it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, this is true, of course. On the other hand, this is a good motivation for the OP to hear about Cauchy's Theorem.